# Cart empties itself very quickly

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1

I have an issue that when someone puts an item in the shopping cart, the cart empties itself very quickly and erases everything they had in the cart. This needs to not happen, when a customer puts products into the cart, they need to stay in the cart for weeks at a time. 
The longest an item stayed in my cart for was 1.5 days.
what can be the reason?
please advise.

I set up "Quote Lifetime (days)" to 7 at Admin->System->Config->Sales->Checkout->Shopping cart

Thanks

Comment: The problem is with the cart only or to you have troubles with the logged in customers? Are they logged out very quickly after logging in? I'm asking this because I had a similar issue and it was actually a session issue. The server was not configured correctly.

Comment: I have not tested with the logged in customers , but session.gc_maxlifetime value is 1440 , can this be an issue ?

Comment: That means 24 minutes. It's not much but should be enough to be able to place an order.

Answer (score 5):

**In my experience** the session expiration is tied to using **filesystem sessions** and PHP garbage collection. Try the following to test this out:

- Switch your session storage to MySQL or to APC/Memcached/Redis (not a long term solution, to be sure, but for testing)

If it turns out this is the case, **[raise your gc (Garbage Collection) max lifetime value](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)** in htaccess, php.ini or in your index.php:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253498/declaring-session-max-life-time-in-htaccess

In my experience switching to PHP FPM also helped to alleviate these GC issues.